# Por que o readonly é valido no formulário?

Tags: javascript, html5, formulário

Acabei de perceber que o `readonly` no `input` está dando como válido, mesmo não contendo nenhuma informação.

- Por que isto acontece?
- Como proceder para validar o `input` com este atributo?

Exemplo:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('RSPIUF').checkValidity())
```

```html
<input type="text" id="RSPIUF" name="registration-step-personal-information-uf" class="form-control" aria-describedby="UF" placeholder="UF" readonly required>
```

Comment: Na verdade  `readonly` e `required` no mesmo input é no mínimo estranho...

Comment: @hugocsl eu estou tentando fazer o seguinte.. Este é um daqueles campos que só irá ser inserido o `value` assim que digitar o CEP (ai será feito a consulta na API do correio), correto? Porém esta informação é obrigatória a ter. O que você aconselha?

Comment: Mas por que seria `readonly`? E se a informação vier errada e o usuário precisar corrigir?

Comment: Vc tem que validar o campo que alimenta o readonly e não o campo readonly

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss não, o único `input` que se altera é o do CEP. O `readonly` ele é somente para leitura. Porém a diferença do `readonly` e do `disabled` é que o `readonly` é encaminhado para o formulário, logo o `disabled` não.

Comment: @hugocsl poderia me explicar o porque disto e o porque é estranho ter o required com ele?

Comment: Sim, não entendi o que isso interfere no que comentei. Se você colocar, por exemplo, o nome da rua como `readonly` o usuário não poderá editar, nem se essa informação veio errada - e se for usar a API dos Correios, acredite, isso é muito mais comum do que imagina.

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS acho que vc já tem uma resposta, mas é por esse motivo tão obvio quanto parece.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Não que seja válido, ele simplesmente não passa pela API checkValidity. A API ignora campos input com o atributo `readonly`, ou seja, o atributo `required` não vai ter efeito algum. [Veja aqui](http://www.w3c-test.org/html/semantics/forms/constraints/form-validation-willValidate.html) uma lista de elementos ignorados pela API, onde diz também que:

> [INPUT in TEXT status] Must be barred from the constraint validation
>   if it is readonly

Tradução Google:

> [INPUT in TEXT status] Deve ser barrado da validação de restrição se
>   for somente leitura

Sem entrar na questão de estar usando um input de texto readonly vazio ou a razão de fazer isso, você *poderia* (não que devesse) verificar o campo sem o uso da API, por exemplo, verificando se ele está vazio e barrar o submit:

```js
document.forms[0].onsubmit = function(){
   if(!document.getElementById('RSPIUF').value.trim()){
      alert("Campo vazio");
      return false;
   }
}
```

```html
<form action="./">
   <input type="text" id="RSPIUF" name="registration-step-personal-information-uf" class="form-control" aria-describedby="UF" placeholder="UF" readonly required>
   <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Seria sábio e confiável validar somente o campo que alimenta este `input` com `readonly`?

Comment: Pode validar somente o campo que alimenta, já bastaria. O importante mesmo é validar no backend se vc for usá-lo de alguma forma.

Comment: Deixei meu -1 só porque não vejo justificativas para se fazer isso, pois é uma solução para um problema que o próprio desenvolvedor inseriu. Ao meu ver, faz mais sentido evitar o problema do que resolvê-lo e para isso bastaria remover o `readonly` do campo - e isso inclusive impactaria positivamente na experiência do usuário, pois não o privaria de fazer uma ação que pode fazer (alterar os dados).

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss blz, agradeço o voto, mesmo sendo negativo, e pela franqueza tb. Apesar de não estar explicitado na pergunta, o AP comentou que o campo é alimentado por outro campo (?)... sem entrar no mérito da forma que ele está fazendo isso (se é a melhor, se está correta ou não) apenas abordei o fato do campo com `readonly` ser ignorado pela API, que foi o ponto central da pergunta, aliás o único ponto. Mas valeu aí! Abs!

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss aproveitando, se possui uma resposta que acha mais correta, por favor, poste aí e nos ajude a melhorar a qualidade do tópico. Abs!

Answer (score 6):

Um campo definido como `readonly` tem por finalidade apenas apresentar uma informação ao usuário de forma que seja enviada junto com os dados na submissão do formulário. Como o próprio nome diz é um campo de apenas leitura, então parte-se da premissa que o campo possua o atributo `value`, mesmo que vazio (pois um valor vazio pode ser um valor válido).

**Por que ele retorna `true` na validação?**

Porque ele sempre será válido. Os valores em um campo `readonly` serão definidos pela própria aplicação e, portanto, sempre serão válidos. Porém, não retorna `true` por esse motivo, na verdade um campo `readonly` nem passa pela validação.

Conforme a [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#the-readonly-attribute):

> Constraint validation: If the `readonly` attribute is specified on an input element, the element is barred from constraint validation.

Ou seja, se o atributo `readonly` for especificado em um campo, o elemento é barrado da validação.

**Então como posso validar um campo `readonly`?**

Não valida. Não o campo, pelo menos. Você citou que está aplicando isso para exibir o resultado de uma busca de endereço na API dos Correios a partir do CEP informado pelo usuário, ao meu ver você estará utilizando o atributo de forma errada nesta situação. Informações do endereço do usuário são de responsabilidade do usuário e ele pode querer alterá-las, não faz sentido privá-lo disso. Inclusive é bastante comum que o resultado da API venha incorreto. Nomes de ruas mudam, CEPs mudam... acredite, você não vai querer ter seu sistema confiando cegamente na API.

**Meu conselho é remover os atributos `readonly` desses campo**. Isso, inclusive, impacta positivamente na experiência do seu usuário. Deixe ele fazer aquilo que é esperado ele poder fazer.

Talvez em alguma situação muito específica seja realmente necessário fazer essa validação no valor do campo `readonly`, mas para isso faça **antes de definir o valor**. Não faz sentido você atribuir um valor inválido no campo para depois validá-lo. Valide-o antes, ainda na sua aplicação e só insira no campo se ele for válido.